# Load jar dynamically at runtime?

Tags: java, classloader

My current java project is using methods and variables from another project (same package). Right now the other project's jar has to be in the classpath to work correctly. My problem here is that the name of the jar can and will change because of increasing versions, and because you cannot use wildcards in the manifest classpath, it's impossible to add it to the classpath. So currently the only option of starting my application is using the `-cp` argument from the command line, manually adding the other jar my project depends on.

To improve this, I wanted to load the jar dynamically and read about using the ClassLoader. I read a lot of examples for it, however I still don't understand how to use it in my case.

What I want is it to load a jar file, lets say, `myDependency-2.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but it should be able to just search for a jar file starting with `myDependency-` because as I already said the version number can change at anytime. Then I should just be able to use it's methods and variables in my Code just like I do now (like `ClassInMyDependency.exampleMethod()`).

Can anyone help me with this, as I've been searching the web for a few hours now and still don't get how to use the ClassLoader to do what I just explained.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: On the basis that your (+1) question demonstrates a fair amount of research, I've added a "give me the codez" solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Applies to Java version 8 and earlier).

---

Indeed this is occasionally necessary. This is how I do this in production. It uses reflection to circumvent the encapsulation of `addURL` in the system class loader.

```
/*
     * Adds the supplied Java Archive library to java.class.path. This is benign
     * if the library is already loaded.
     */
    public static synchronized void loadLibrary(java.io.File jar) throws MyException
    {
        try {
            /*We are using reflection here to circumvent encapsulation; addURL is not public*/
            java.net.URLClassLoader loader = (java.net.URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            java.net.URL url = jar.toURI().toURL();
            /*Disallow if already loaded*/
            for (java.net.URL it : java.util.Arrays.asList(loader.getURLs())){
                if (it.equals(url)){
                    return;
                }
            }
            java.lang.reflect.Method method = java.net.URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{java.net.URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true); /*promote the method to public access*/
            method.invoke(loader, new Object[]{url});
        } catch (final java.lang.NoSuchMethodException | 
            java.lang.IllegalAccessException | 
            java.net.MalformedURLException | 
            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException e){
            throw new MyException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why system class loader is used in this case?

Comment: In Java 11 (OpenJDK 11.0.12 2021-07-20) there occurs an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`. This one works in Java 11 / OpenJDK 11: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48323948/10318272

Comment: @S.Doe: Yes, you are correct. I've added a cautionary note. Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

I needed to load a jar file at runtime for both java 8 and java 9+. Here is the method to do it (using Spring Boot 1.5.2 if it may relate).

```
public static synchronized void loadLibrary(java.io.File jar) {
    try {            
        java.net.URL url = jar.toURI().toURL();
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = java.net.URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{java.net.URL.class});
        method.setAccessible(true); /*promote the method to public access*/
        method.invoke(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), new Object[]{url});
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot load library from jar file '" + jar.getAbsolutePath() + "'. Reason: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```